# Tableau desktop not connecting to DB server on AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tableau-api, windows-server-2012

My postgres DB is in AWS instance running windows server 2012.
My tableau desktop is in local machine.

While connecting to the DB using external instance IP and default postgres PORT 5432 , it shows the error

> Unable to connect to the ODBC Data Source.
> Check that the necessary drivers are installed and that the connection     properties are valid.
> Unable to connect to the server "ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com".
> Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.

I have made sure that:

1. AWS security group is configured for all incoming ports
2. Windows server 2012 firewall is accepting all inbound traffic.
3. My local desktop is allowing to send traffic to remote server.And I can `telnet hostIP/hostname PORT` successfully.
4. Postgres service is running on 5432 port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I have not set the pg_hba.conf file correctly for postgres. Allowing the connection request from all external IPs let me resolve the issue.

Adding the line at the end of the file,

```
host all postgres 0.0.0.0 md5
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the points you mentioned, I would suggest to see if you have the required drivers installed for postgres. Also, if possible for you for the time being you can install any client temporarily like sqldeveloper(later you can remove this) on the tableau desktop.

Now because you are able to telnet Ip 5432, you can test your connection from the client, If this doesnt work u know that the problem is in configuration else we need to dig more into that.

Comment: I assume by suggesting "required drivers installed" you mean to ask , drivers are installed in AWS server. Yes, drivers are installed in AWS server.@Niceha

Comment: Also can you be more specific on installing sql client on tableau desktop.

Comment: @angrysumit : SQL client is e.g you may use sql developer tool, If you can query your server from this tool.This will ensure that you have connectivity and access to DB. Then there is some problem with the db link or credentials which u are using to connect